# Java MySql Connection Through DSN

Tags: java, mysql, dsn

I am trying to connect to one of my MySql Databases through a System DSN I set up. The DSN is set up correctly with my SSL certs, username, password, port, and the databases populate the DSN database drop down and the "Test" connection passes. I can't seem to get a connection in Java. I have spent 2 days looking through some examples on Stack but they all refer to an Access database and using JDBC-ODBC bridge which is no longer available in Java 8. I tried using UCanAccess with Jackcess but I have gotten no where. The code below is what I have been tinkering with the last few hours. I normally connect to MySql databases with PHP and receive result in JSON or directly with JDBC driver but for this project neither are really an option. Any ideas. I appreciate the help.

```
//String username = "<username>";
//String password = "<password>";
//String database = "<database_name>";

try {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

    //Connect to cllients MySql Database
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:" + database);

    //Call VerifyLabel(<MAC>,<MODEL>); Call provided client
    CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL verify(?, ?)}");

    //MAC
    cStmt.setString(1, "mac address");

    //model            
    cStmt.setString(2, "model");

    cStmt.execute();

    //Getting results from "Status" column
    ResultSet rs1 = cStmt.getResultSet();

    //Iterate results and print.
    while (rs1.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs1.getString("Status"));
    }

    //Close connection conn
    rs1.close();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CambiumStoredTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CambiumStoredTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Using MySql Driver:

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:"+ database);
```

also tried:

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ database);
```

Error for MySql Driver:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: UCanAccess is only intended for use with Access.  I wouldn't expect it to work with MySQL at all, in the same way that I wouldn't expect the MySQL JDBC driver to be able to talk to a SQL Server database.  Could you explain why using the MySQL JDBC driver isn't an option?

Comment: MySQL driver is not made to create any `JDBC-ODBC bridge` connection. You should first check which type of driver you want to use. As @LukeWoodward specified, DSN works with ACCESS and Sql Server.

Comment: I was originally using MySql JDBC Driver but was not getting a connection. There is another part of the application written in Visual C that we set up by creating a System DSN after installing the MySql Drivers. This application succesfully posts data to the MySql Database. So, DSN can also work with MySql. I originally used the MySql JDBC drivers but figured it would be easier to setup a DSN because of the SSL certs.

Comment: Even with before Java 8 the ODBC bridge was buggy as hell and slow. Using a native JDBC driver is always the better choice.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale: that's not true. ODBC datasource can very well point to _any_ DBMS that has an ODBC driver including MySQL (and of course many other DBMS as well like Postgres, Oracle, DB2 - not just SQL Server). But using the ODBC bridge in Java is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1) DSN is most commonly assocatiated with ODBC (and often with MS-Access).  Hence all the links.  ODBC is *NOT* required for a DSN.

2) Do *NOT* use Ucanaccess.  Use [J/Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/index.html) for mySQL.

3) Make sure you can communicate with mySQL from the command line.  Then focus on getting a small "hello world" JDBC app to connect.  Your second and third examples look OK.  Be sure to check the mySQL logs for any warnings/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after an entire day of trying to get this to work and sleeping on it for a couple hours I finally got it to work. UCanAccess and mysql-connector did not work. The easiest thing since no other method of connecting to this clients database was acceptable was to push this application in Java 7 rather than 8. This allowed me to Coo=nnect to my DSN with no problems. I understand that this method is not the best solution but it is what is working flawlessly and efficiently. Also, instead of using some rigged up 3rd party libs and jars, I am able to use Connector/J. Thanks everyone for trying to help me. Just incase anyone else runs into this issue, this is how I made it work.

1. Develope app in Java 7 - not 8.
2. Set Up System DSN

   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

   //You do not need to provide username or password if it is setup in DSN
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:"+ database);